# convert sparse matrix form matlab format into ijv coordinate format

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have sparse matrices in matlab format and I want to convert them into ijv coordinate format sorted by row(the first column) . Below is my attempt but it is not so efficient because the matrices are very large(sometimes nnz > 1M) and this code requires a lot of memory. Any better idea is highly appreciated.

```
function printIJV(file_name,S)
  % S is the sparse matrix in Matlab storing only nonzero values and their indices.e.g (1,1) 20 , (2,1) 30 , (3,2) 22 ,...
  [i,j,v] = find(S);
 temp2 = [i,j,v];
 temp = sortrows(temp2 ,temp2(1) );
  file_id = fopen(file_name,'wt');
  % header: n-rows n-columns n-values
  fprintf(file_id,'%d %d %d\n', size(S,1) ,size(S,2),size(v,1) );
  n = size(temp , 1);
  for i=1:n
  %minus one for zero-based indexing
  fprintf(file_id,'%d %d %g\n',temp(i,1)-1 , temp(i,2)-1 , temp(i,3));
  end
  fclose(file_id);
end
```

Comment: Is `S` a sparse matrix? (Please edit it into the question.) `find` and `sortrows` are probably each as optimized as it could be. Writing to file is writing to file. By all means, you can splice the matrix into multiple parts if memory is a concern. You are probably thinking whether there is a function/utility that combines `find` and `sortrows` for sparse matrix. To that end, I don't think there is. The functions for sparse matrix I come across are all for manipulating matrices based on sparsity. Plus, there is probably little advantage. You can always time each component of your code

Comment: in order to identify which part is the culprit of inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
[j,i,v] = find(S')
```